# Vagrant difference between package and repackage

Tags: vagrant

What is the difference between `vagrant box repackage` ([docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/box.html)) and `vagrant package` ([docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html))?

I realise that `vagrant package` works only with the VirtualBox provider, but in case only VirtualBox is used - what's the difference? Maybe there's a specific reason `vagrant package` was created?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**vagrant package**

If you have a running VirtualBox VM, you created without vagrant first, did your things using VirtualBox, and you now want to use Vagrant to manage this VM. As vagrant needs box to start VM, you will run `vagrant package` to create a vagrant box based on the existing VirtualBox VM

**vagrant repackage**

You will use this option when you have an existing vagrant box installed on your system. So you use vagrant with a given box, again you will make change to the VM and you want to save those changes (software installed ...) as a new box, you will run `vagrant repackage` on this box, and it will create an updated version of this box so it can be used as starting box for new VM.

Comment: Somehow the `repackage` command doesn't exist anymore (1.9.2). Is there a way to package the current state of the vm as a base including the private key and networking settings of the current Vagrantfile?  for virtualbox i'm currently operating like ```vagrant package --base "vm_name_default_1239123913_1233213" --output "package.box" --vagrantfile Vagrantfile``` where --base parameter points to the actual virtualbox vm and not the vagrant box used. Is this the accepted way to do so?

Comment: `repackage` is part of the options from `vagrant box` and it still seems to be available so `vagrant box repackage ...` will do the job. else your command will also achieve the same but if you start from an existing vagrant box, I'll go for `vagrant box repackage ...`

Comment: @Cyrus `vagrant box repackage`, you have to add `box` infront of `repackage`. What `repackage`does is that it repackages the original state of the VM, following the metadata_url in `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/abc-VAGRANTSLASH-abc/metadata_url`. The url is specified to the link the box first was pulled from. So the only known way for me is to use `package` to get the current state of the box.

Comment: vagrant package --output 'name.box' will create a package out of a vagrant vm from your current path, and its fine for it to have been created with vagrant, so I don't see how this answer is correct.

Comment: Do I HAVE to use `vagrant repackage` if I'm creating a new box that was originally created using another Vagrant image? Or can I still do `vagrant package`.

Answer (score 12):

I will answer with the specific example of the VirtualBox provider on macOS, but this can be generalized to any provider on any host. Although not asked by the op, I will also explain `--base NAME` because I think it helps in clarifying the difference. I will also use the `--output OUTPUT_NAME` to distinguish between the packaged boxes.

## vagrant package

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > vagrant package --output vm1-package.box
```

1. Attempts graceful shutdown of currently running VM which is found from `./.vagrant/...` directory
2. Clears any previously set forwarded ports
3. Exports the VM (using the provider's export tools) and adds vagrant_private_key
4. Archives (using `tar`) everything into `./vm1-package.box`

```
==> vm1: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> vm1: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> vm1: Exporting VM...
==> vm1: Compressing package to: /Users/user/code/vagrant/vm1/vm1-package.box
```

To verify:

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > tar -C /tmp/vm1 -xvf ./vm1-package.box
```

```
x ./vagrant_private_key
x ./metadata.json
x ./box.ovf
x ./Vagrantfile
x ./box-disk001.vmdk
```

Since this packages the currently running VM that **Vagrant** manages, the above list includes the `vagrant_private_key` file (which is loaded by the packaged `Vagrantfile`).

Now, we can add this box to Vagrant's internal storage in `~/.vagrant.d`:

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > vagrant box add vm1-package.box --name vm1
```

```
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'vm1' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file:///Users/user/code/vagrant/vm1/vm1-package.box
==> box: Successfully added box 'vm1' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
```

which you can also verify by:

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > ls -lF ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/vm1/0/virtualbox/
```

```
total 1152400
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff        630 13 Dec 16:26 Vagrantfile
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  575710720 13 Dec 16:26 box-disk001.vmdk
-rwx------  1 user  staff       6838 13 Dec 16:26 box.ovf*
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff         25 13 Dec 16:26 metadata.json
-rw-------  1 user  staff       1675 13 Dec 16:26 vagrant_private_key
```

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > vagrant box list
```

```
hashicorp/bionic64              (virtualbox, 1.0.282)
vm1                             (virtualbox, 0)
```

## vagrant package --base vm_name

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > vagrant package --base vm1 --output vm1-base-package.box
```

1. Attempts graceful shutdown of currently running VM which is found from `./.vagrant/...` directory
2. Clears any previously set forwarded ports
3. Exports the VM (using the provider's export tools) but does not add vagrant_private_key
4. Archives (using `tar`) everything into `./vm1-base-package.box`

```
==> vm1: Exporting VM...
==> vm1: Compressing package to: /Users/user/code/vagrant/vm1/vm1-base-package.box
```

To verify:

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > tar -C /tmp/vm1-base -xvf ./vm1-base-package.box
```

```
x ./metadata.json
x ./box.ovf
x ./Vagrantfile
x ./box-disk001.vmdk
```

Since this packages the currently running VM that **Virtualbox** manages, the above list does not includes the `vagrant_private_key` file.

Now, we can add this box to Vagrant's internal storage in `~/.vagrant.d`:

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > vagrant box add vm1-base-package.box --name vm1-base
```

```
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'vm1-base' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file:///Users/user/code/vagrant/vm1/vm1-base-package.box
==> box: Successfully added box 'vm1-base' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
```

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > vagrant box list
```

```
hashicorp/bionic64              (virtualbox, 1.0.282)
vm1                             (virtualbox, 0)
vm1-base                        (virtualbox, 0)
```

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > ls -lF *.box
```

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  561848649 13 Dec 16:50 vm1-base-package.box
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  561767838 13 Dec 16:19 vm1-package.box
```

If you delete the box files from the current directory...

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > rm *.box
```

... you may now use `vagrant repackage` to get them back:

## vagrant box repackage

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > vagrant box repackage vm1 virtualbox 0
```

This takes the files from Vagrant's internal storage `~/.vagrant.d/...` and re-packages them back into a box in the current directory called package.box. In this case, you cannot name the file using the command, so you may want to rename it:

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > mv package.box vm1-package.box
```

and for the base box:

```
~/code/vagrant/vm1 > vagrant box repackage vm1-base virtualbox 0

~/code/vagrant/vm1 > mv package.box vm1-base.box

~/code/vagrant/vm1 > ls -lF *.box
```

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  561848571 13 Dec 17:28 vm1-base.box
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  561767855 13 Dec 17:24 vm1-package.box
```

## Additional note

The manual is not very clear on the syntax of the `vagrant package` command with and without the --base option. I think the clarification should be:

```
vagrant package [options] [vm_name|vm_id]
```

It should specify that if [vm_name|vm_id] is not specified, then the currently running VM is packaged, otherwirse, the VM specified by [vm_name|vm_id] is packaged.

It should also specify that if you use the --base option, the command should be:

```
vagrant package --base MANDATORY_NAME [vm_name|id]
```

but in this case, [vm_name|id] is completely ignored, since the VM has already been specified by MANDATORY_NAME

I verified this by issuing:
    vagrant package --base vm1 --output vm1-base-package.box non-existent-vm-name
and it still generated vm1-base-package.box without any errors.