# Correct way to back-up and restore vagrant box + Variable VVV

Tags: vagrant

I have a vagrant box (ubuntu/trusty64) installed on my MacBook. I have extended this box with Variable VVV --> https://github.com/bradp/vv#os-x-installation
This enables me to create fresh WordPress installs (currently I have around 10 installs).

I want to completely clear out my MacBook and install a fresh version, but I don't want to lose my box and all of my projects. How can I tackle this problem without losing my projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to backup your box, your project directory and the virtualbox folder with all the VM.

Those are the following:

- ~/.vagrant.d folder all together

This folder has all your downloaded boxes (under the ~/.vagrant.d/boxes folder) but also has the references of all the VM that are active under vagrant management

- Your project directory

save the folders where you have Vagrantfile, they also contains a `.vagrant` directory, under this folder there is file with the reference of the VM linked with this Vagrantfile

- The VM directory

I am not sure the default value but should be `~/VirtualBox VMs`. Backup this directory which contains the VMs created by vagrant

After you have cleaned up your macos, you need to make sure you reinstall those folders at the same location

Comment: Ah nice thank you! By "reinstal those folders" you mean install the vagrant box and the VM after that i need to copy all the old folders back right?

Comment: yep install vagrant and virtualbox software then copy the folders I mention so you can get all your configured VM as they were before

Answer (score 7):

You can package your working VM into a new vagrant box

```
vagrant package --output ./new-box-name.box
```

and then backup this box

After you reinstall your Mackbook, you can then add this box to your local vagrant directory

```
vagrant box add new-box-name ./new-box-name.box
```

After that you initiate the vagrantfile through

```
vagrant init mynewbox
```

You will get back the same VM as what you have before

Comment: I'm all for backups but this answer is the best in my opinion, will be the least expensive in terms of storage and is the only thing required to be able to recreate the environments (is the `vagrant` way to do it). However I will note that `vagrant box repackage` is probably what you would want to use if the VM was initially created from an existing box, ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667543/1423507

Comment: Good solution, but won't work with VMWare Fusion unless you have the Pro version (as it needs to run `vmrun clone` in the background)

Comment: Note this shuts your machine down. As I just found out. Ha!

Comment: It worked flawlessly

Comment: Will the new vagrantfile be exactly the same as the old vagrantfile with this solution? Including custom public IP address and port mapping settings.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you use Github. You will basically be uploading your files to github. Whenever ur ready to get them back you can easily pull the project from github heres a link with more information on how to use github. 
http://product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: I am already using github for my projects.. Do you mean re-install the virtual box and the VM and just import all the projects again?

Comment: Yeah, thats what i thought